# How can i update an SQLite database in an android app?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-database

I'm building an android application with Android Studio. I store datas in an SQLite database. I can execute query on this database without problems.

However, I need to update the database with an online one. To do so I get it from an SFTP (connection with JSch) and want to replace the old one (in the application) with the new one from the SFTP. The fact is I can't find the path to the database on my application.

I tried :

```
String destinationPath = _currenContext.getDatabasePath("database.db").toString();
```

And

```
String destinationPath = "data/data/" + _currenContext.getPackageName() + "/databases/database.db";
```

Also when I print the first one i get this path :

```
data/user/0/com.myApp.android/databases/database.db
```

None of them reach me to the database : always get "No such file or directory".

Could someone helps me ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [getAbsolutePath()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()) method instead of the toString() method on the File object:

```
String destinationPath = _currenContext.getDatabasePath("database.db").getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: After many searches and trying to understand how SQLite works on android I found that the database is stored in tha apk at the installation.If you don't open the database or make any query, the database is kept in the apk. 

So you need to make at least one query so the SQLite database is extracted from the apk and placed in the good folder. 

Thanks for your answer, either .getAbsolutePath() and .toString() methods works !